# How do I get data from a server without showing it in a widget in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, asynchronous, download

I'm new to Flutter and I've already learned how to get JSON data from a server and show it in a ListView, for instance. Now I would like to download some tables when the app starts an store them in lists to use afterwards. All the examples and tutorials I've found use some widgets to show the data immediately after downloading.
I wonder if what I want to do is possible in Flutter and if you could refer me to an example.
Of course I have no code to show because I have not tried anything yet, that's how lost I am...
Thanks.

Comment: yes you can do that It is not necessary to display each data you receive. So how do you want to store them like store during an application or store offline?

Comment: It is during the application execution time. Thanks for considering helping me, but after more research I was able to figure out how to do it.